# Wicket Mounted Urls Are Case Sensitive?

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

Can anyone tell me how to mount case insensitive urls in wicket?

the mountPage ("/home", HomePage.class) doesnt map for /Home for example. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in Wicket 7.0.0-M1 - since https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4994.

Comment: Just the answer I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, as I see it, is to write a filter (implement the javax.servlet.Filter interface), and do url 
manipulation there.

You can get a good example from [Servlet Filters](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html) for doing this.